# Allowing two individuals with android phones to communicate via an app that's not the built-in messaging app

Tags: android, messaging

I basically want to make an android app that will allow peer-to-peer text messaging without the messages going into the phone's SMS inbox/outbox, but rather shown in the app's interface. Any help is appreciated. I'm new to android mobile development.

Comment: This is too broad of a question as a lot will have to go into it..try to do the design in stages (i.e. GUI, then functionality, then storage, etc.) and individually research each piece you come across that you don't know how to do. But I wouldn't count on anyone posting a step-by-step guide on how to do it here.

Comment: I'm basically working on the functionality part by attempting to get the phones to communicate with each other. I have the GUI, and like you said storage will come later.

Comment: How should the communication work? Text messages or over a custom server? If latter, then look a client server communications and push notifications.

Comment: It is the latter. Will I need to use sockets? Could you direct me to some relevant reading on client server communications in relation to the Android DE?